# .NET Core Web Api cannot access the models folder

Tags: .net-core, namespaces

I have two project in my solution. MVC and WebAPI. I added the WebAPI project later. I added new controller and Models folder in WebAPI project. But I can't create a new instance of my model in the controller. I get "The type or namespace name 'Category' could not be found..". It also doesn't allow me to bind the name using.MyProjectAPI.Models.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on Reference and click Add Project Reference

Comment: my controller and my model are both in the WebAPI project

Comment: Check if the Model is Public or not if it is private make it public or Check namespace